# Как открыть балун метки на яндекс карте по клику на внешнюю ссылку

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Есть список магазинов. И есть точки этих магазинов на карте. По клику на магазин в списке я получаю координаты этого магазина и центрирую карту по этим координатам. Но как мне получить метку, которая по этим координатам находится и открыть балун этой метки?

```
$('.shop').on('click', function(){
    var coords = $(this).data('coords');
    myMap.setCenter(coords , 15);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение. Я сначала центрирую карту по координатам метки, а затем через geoQuery получаю центральный объект и открываю его балун. Элегантно и просто на мой скромный взгляд

```
ymaps.geoQuery(myMapCollection).getCentralObject(myMap).balloon.open();
```